# Differentiate $y =\sin(1+x^2)^{1/2}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

I've tried differentiating $y= \sin(1+x^2)^{1/2}$ using the chain rule, but I keep getting the wrong answer. Can anyone give me a step by step so I can see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You mean $\sqrt{\sin(1+x^2)}$ or $\sin\sqrt{1+x^2}$?

Comment: Why don't you show what you keep getting wrong (your work), then we can point out what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Well I was getting xcos(1+x^2)^-1/2 and didn't understand where the sin was coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean $y=\sqrt{\sin(1+x^2)}$:

$$\begin{align}y'=&\frac{1}{2}(\sin(1+x^2))^{-\frac12}\cdot\underbrace{\frac{d}{dx}(\sin(1+x^2))}_{\text{Use the chain rule again!}}\\=&\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\sin(1+x^2)}}\cdot\cos(1+x^2)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}(1+x^2)\\=&\frac{2x\cos(1+x^2)}{2\sqrt{\sin(1+x^2)}}=\frac{x\cos(1+x^2)}{\sqrt{\sin(1+x^2)}}\end{align}$$

Comment: Where you got y'= 1/2(SIN(1+x²))^-1/2.   Why is it sin and not cos?

Comment: However great answer. Thanks!

Comment: The whole first line is the chain rule. So, first we apply the power rule, and then we multiply by the derivative of $\sqrt{\sin(1+x^2)}$.

Comment: Oh I get it now! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

by the chaine and power rule we obtain $\frac{1}{2}(\sin(1+x^2))^{-1/2}\cos(1+x^2)2x$
at first $\sqrt{\sin(1+x^2)}$ by the power rule, then we get $\cos(1+x^2)$ by the chain rule and $2x$ by the chaine rule.

Answer (score 0):

If $y=\sqrt{u}$, $u=\sin(v)$, and $v=1+x^2$, then

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{du}\cdot \frac{du}{dv}\cdot \frac{dv}{dx}$$

So,

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}\cdot \cos(v)\cdot(2x)$$

Expressing this in terms of $x$, we get:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\sin(1+x^2)}}\cdot \cos(1+x^2)\cdot(2x)=\frac{x\cos(1+x^2)}{\sqrt{\sin(1+x^2)}}$$

This is similar with the answers of the guys previously, where the idea is the "Chain Rule". I have posted this answer because one may find it more clear.